# Errors in custom list view "in which each row consist of 2 textviews and a checkbox"

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

I wrote a code that retrieve data from server and display them in a  simple list and it work successfully,but when  I use a custom list view "in which each row consist of textviews and checkbox" it doesn't work..

this is my classes:

```
public class ItemInList {
private String name;
private float Description;
private boolean selected;

public ItemInList(String name, float Description) {
    this.name = name;
    this.Description =Description;
    selected = false;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public float getDescription() {
    return Description;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public void setDescription(float Description) {
    this.Description = Description;
}

public boolean isSelected() {
    return selected;
}

public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
    this.selected = selected;
}
```

this is the adapter class

```
public class DataAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ItemInList> {


public ArrayList<ItemInList> list;

public Activity context;
public LayoutInflater inflater;

public DataAdapter(Activity context,int x,ArrayList<ItemInList> list) {
    super(context, 0, list);
    this.context = context;
    this.list = list;
    this.inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

static class ViewHolder {
    protected TextView name,Description;
    protected CheckBox checkbox;
}

public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return list.size();
}

@Override
public ItemInList getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return list.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder;



    if (convertView == null) {

         holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row1, null);


        holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.food_title);
        holder.name.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

        holder.Description = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.food_description);
        holder.Description.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);

        holder.checkbox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.add_food_item);
    //viewHolder.checkbox
                //.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                    //@Override
                    //public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                            //boolean isChecked) {
                        //ItemInList element = (ItemInList) viewHolder.checkbox.getTag();
                        //element.setSelected(buttonView.isChecked());
                        //System.out.println("Checked : " + element.getName());
                    //}
                //});

         convertView.setTag(holder);


    } else {
         holder=(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();

            ItemInList bean = (ItemInList) list.get(position);

            holder.name.setText( bean.getName());
            holder.Description.setText( bean.getDescription()+"");
            holder.checkbox.setChecked( bean.isSelected());

              return convertView;
    }



    holder.name.setText(list.get(position).getName());
    holder.Description.setText(list.get(position).getDescription()+"");
    holder.checkbox.setChecked(list.get(position).isSelected());

      return convertView;
}
```

Comment: When you say "it doesn't work", what do you mean?  Does it throw an exception?  If so, please provide the stack trace.  If not, what is the expected behavior and what is the behavior you are seeing?  Thanks!

Comment: You have a NullPointerException in doInBackground of LoadData, at line 171 of AddFoodActivity.  Can you mark that line above, since I don't have the full file?  There's a lot going on in this method.

Comment: line 171 points to line that contain } at the end of class .  may it mean the last line **return null **at the end .

Comment: The exception provided by you comes from progressDialog.dismiss() in onPostExecute. This is because the Activity got destroyed due to an unhandled exception in AsyncTask's doInBackground() (so progressDialog.dismiss causes the exception because there is no parent context anymore). So look up in your log..there should be another error/warning

Comment: yes there is a warning :thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409951f8).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not initate your

```
ItemInList item;
```

before setting the values in doInBackground()

```
item.setName(foodName);
//...
```

Comment: i make it equal null as initial value, I get the same errors.

Comment: Yes thats the problem. Declaration -> Instantiation -> Initialization. Initiate it like: item = new ItemInList()

Answer (score 0):

Does it work if you remove "return null" from LoadData.doInBackground()?  It's a void function, after all, which shouldn't return anything.

Comment: this error appear if i delete it - The return type is incompatible with AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>.doInBackground (Void[])